# Value from Form2 not updating in Form2

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have 2 forms in C# desktop application. Form1 and Form2.

Form1 contains a public method that adds item in ListBox control as follows:

```
public void AddToList(string item)
{
    listBox.Items.Add(item);
}
```

When I call this method directly on some button press then it works fine. But when I call this method from Form2, it doesn't add anything in ListBox control on Form1. Code in Form2 is as below:

```
Form1 frm = new Form1();
frm.AddToList("something");
```

When I run this nothing happens. No error nothing. It just doesn't add any item into ListBox.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sounds like you are creating a new instance of Form1 rather than referencing the existing instance in your GUI.  Can you post more of your GUI-layer code where Form1 and Form2 are shown/used?

Comment: You have two *types* in your project.  But you are creating more than one *object* of each type.  Add frm.Show() to see your mistake.

Comment: How are you creating your two forms? Are they both created by a third form like MDI, or is Form1 creating Form2, or how? This will help us provide an answer on how to get your two forms talking to each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating a *new* instance of Form1 and adding an item to it's listbox, rather than getting an instance of the Form1 you no doubt already have and calling the method on that.

The naive approach is to have a parameter in the Form2 constructor that takes an instance of Form1 and saves it as an instance variable for use in this event handler.

I don't much like that approach from a design perspective.

I would suggest creating a public event in Form2, having Form1 subscribe to that event and add a handler that add the item to the listbox.  The Event in Form2 would look something like this:

```
public event EventHandler ButtonClick
{
    add
    {
        button1.Click += value;
    }
    remove
    {
        button1.Click += value;
    }
}
```

Then you'll have a property that looks something like this:

```
public string SomeValueForm1NeedsOnButtonClick
{
    get
    {
        return texbox1.Text;
    }
}
```

Then in Form1 you'll have something like:

```
Form2 otherForm = new Form2();
otherForm.ButtonClick += (sender, args) =>
{
    listbox1.Items.Add(otherForm.SomeValueForm1NeedsOnButtonClick);
};
```

This approach ensures that each form only knows as little as possible about each other form.  It reduces Coupling between the two classes and makes it clearer to future users/readers of the forms exactly what communication takes place between them.

Comment: I am getting error "A local variable named 'sender' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning...." on this line "otherForm.ButtonClick += (sender, args) =>"

Comment: @Ali Just call 'sender' something else in one of the two contexts.  I didn't use it here, so there's nothing else to update.

Comment: @Ali Keep in mind this isn't meant to be taken verbatim, it's a high level what it should look like.  At a minimum, most of the variable names should be changed to what they actually represent.  This general pattern is something you can use for all sorts of problems with different types of actions/events.

Answer (score 0):

`Form1 frm = new Form1();`

this line is creating a brand new instance of Form2... not the same instance that is already displayed on the screen.  so you are adding to the listbox of this secondary instance that is never shown on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm

If you followed that code with frm.Show() you would have seen it. Isuspect that's not waht you want.

Your approach to the is problem is a tad naive.

You could add a property to form2 and set it to the Form1 instnace you want to use. (PS form1 and form2 are not helping, give them propernames. MainForm and DetailForm or somesuch).

The problem with the above is you've implemented a horrible dependancy.

Lots of ways to go with this, one would be a seperate class to hold the list (an interface and a class would be even better).
Then add a property to Form1 and Form2 of teh ihneterface or class type.

Form2 can then add things to the list.
That raises a list changed event.
Form1 hooks into with an event handler and then refreshes the listbox it's using to display the the doings.

Once you have the infrasturure in polace you can do all sorts of things with it, whereas the method you are using is a lot of code and messing about for very little reward.